# Como checar duas variaveis

Tags: javascript, node.js

Boa Noite, fiz este programa apenas para testes, gostaria de saber se tem como eu adicionar a nota2 como segunda variável e como faria para ela ser checada junto com a not

```js
function calculaNota(nota1) {
    if(isNaN(nota1)) {
        console.log('Você digitou ' + nota1 , 'isso não é um numero')
    }
    else{
        if(nota1 > 10){
            console.log('Voce digitou ' + nota1 ,'e isso é maior que 10' )
        }
    else
        ('Nota registrada com sucesso')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, pode ser feito desta maneira:

```js
function calculaNota(nota1,nota2) {
            
    if(isNaN(nota1) || isNaN(nota2)) {
        isNaN(nota1) ? console.log('Você digitou ' + nota1 + ' isso não é um numero') : console.log('Você digitou ' + nota2 + ' isso não é um numero');

    }
    else{
        if((nota1 > 10) || (nota2>0)){
            nota1 > 10 ? console.log('Voce digitou ' + nota1 ,'e isso é maior que 10' ) : console.log('Voce digitou ' + nota2 + ' e isso é maior que 10' );
        }else{
            ('Nota registrada com sucesso')
        }
    }
}
calculaNota(1,14);
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeito obrigado amigo